# How to initialize redux store from server component using next.js , app router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux

I'm working with Next.js 13, React, and Redux for managing state.

My goal is to load initial data on the server side and display it on the client side. I thought this would be a standard approach with Redux and Next.js, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Here's what I understand:

The Redux store is set up twice: once on the server side, and again on the client side. I thought I could simply fetch data on the server side, use a dispatch function to initialize, and then have the client side load the data. But the problem is that server side components can't use dispatch or manipulate the store data.

The Redux documentation says that React Server Components (RSCs) should not read or write to the Redux store because they can't use hooks or context and aren't meant to be stateful. So, how do we load initial data then? Are initial data exceptions? And if so, how do we update this initial data?

Here is my code, this is RSC

ContactListServerComponent.tsx

```
import ContactList from "@/component/Contacts/page"
import {
  getInitialContactsData,
  initializeContact,
} from "@/lib/features/contacts/contactSlice"
import { makeStore } from "@/lib/store"
import styles from "./contacts.module.scss"

const ContactListPage = async () => {
  const initialData = await getInitialContactsData()
  console.log("server component")
  const store = makeStore()
  store.dispatch(initializeContact(initialData))
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Contacts</h1>
      <ContactList />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactListPage
```

This is Client Page (ContactList)

```
const ContactList = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const contacts = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.contacts)
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string | null>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getContacts())
  }, [dispatch] 

  .... etc
```

I have a server component (ContactListServerComponent.tsx) where I'm trying to fetch and dispatch the initial data. Then, I have a client component (ContactList) where I'm currently using `useEffect` to fetch data, which doesn't fully utilize the benefits of SSR. I'm not sure how to implement my idea to fetch initial data on the server component instead of the client component.

I would like to know how I can load data from API on server component and pass them to client component.

Comment: I haven't really worked with Redux *and* Next.js in combination, but I'd simply pass the data which you fetched server-side as a prop to the client component. Once it is there, you can dispatch it to redux, if you need it there.

Comment: to try  https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs. i also need to this but i have not.

Comment: yes I tried this but this page mentioned just client-side redux things, not server side.